# Ignore keyboard cursor in GTK3 C

Tags: c, gtk3, key-bindings

Using GTK3 in C, I have an interface with buttons.  I want a user with a mouse to be able to press a button OR use press a single button on the keyboard to do the same thing.

MWE (modified from GTK3 Hello World example):

```
/*
 * Ignore keyboard cursor in GTK3 C
 */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void thing() {
    printf("did a thing\n");
}

void otherthing() {
    printf("did something different\n");
}

static gboolean key_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event) {
    gchar* val = gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval);

    if (strcmp(val, "Left") == 0) {
        thing();
    }
    return 0;
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *button2;
    GtkWidget *button_box;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

    button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Do the thing");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("xxx");
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(key_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (thing), window);
    g_signal_connect (button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (otherthing), window);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button2);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

In this program, the user can press the left arrow key to execute `thing`.  The user can also click on the gui button to execute `thing`.  However, hitting certain keyboard keys such as space or enter will "click" on the gui button to execute `thing`.

How do I prevent the keyboard from "clicking" on a button which the keyboard cursor is on in this case?

Comment: I think you need [Accelerator Groups](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html) for this job. Anyway, are you sure that [mnemonics](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-new-with-mnemonic) are not what you need?

Comment: It is hard to understand just because you show a code with a button, because it could be possible that you are talking about focus here which is a thing which behaves differently if you have more then one widget ( 2 buttons for example). By default GTK uses focus on widgets like the button in your case. in therms, when you click a button, that button has focus and this is the reason why space and enter key calls your funtion (activate). You should read more about set-focus, active-focus, and default-focus for that.

Comment: Updated MWE in question with a second button based on @Michi comment.

Comment: @Michi Both accelerators and mnemonics seem inappropriate for what I want to achieve based on my read.  What I am trying to do is a "video game" type interface where buttons like arrow keys are completely in control of certain functions.  I want to have gui buttons in addition to the "video game control" scheme for hardware including a touch screen.  To put it another way, I want the window to have focus, but I never want the gui elements to get individual focus.

Answer (score 0):

### Fake Button Hack

I have hacked a workaround into my code for now using a useless button.  I will not be marking this answer as solved since it is very sloppy, but it does the job until something better becomes available.

#### Description

This hack adds another button with no functions assigned.  Using `gtk_widget_grab_focus`, we force this useless "fakebutton" to hold keyboard focus.  We reissue this command every time a button is pressed.

#### Problems

Grabbing focus back to the fakebutton is slow.  The user can issue a quick succession of commands (in the case of the MWE by pressing <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> to erroneously issue the `otherthing` function).

#### MWE

```
/*
 * Ignore keyboard cursor in GTK3 C
 */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *fakebutton;

void thing() {
    printf("did a thing\n");
}

void otherthing() {
    printf("did something different\n");
}

static gboolean key_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event) {
    gchar* val = gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval);

    if (strcmp(val, "Left") == 0) {
        thing();
        gtk_widget_grab_focus(fakebutton);
    } else {
        gtk_widget_grab_focus(fakebutton);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *button2;
    GtkWidget *button_box;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

    button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Do the thing");
    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("xxx");
    fakebutton = gtk_button_new();
    g_signal_connect(window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(key_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (thing), window);
    g_signal_connect (button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (otherthing), window);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button2);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), fakebutton);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);


    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```